# Header doesn't autosize in ag-grid if header content is longer that column content

Tags: javascript, angular, ag-grid

I;ve got function which autosizes columns or fits them to grid on button click:

```js
 autoSizeGridColumns(params: any, columnsAutoSized: boolean) {
        if (params && params.api) {
            const allColIds = params.columnApi.getAllColumns().map(column => column.getColId());
            if (!columnsAutoSized) {
                params.columnApi.autoSizeColumns(allColIds);
                columnsAutoSized = true;
            } else {
                params.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
                columnsAutoSized = false;
            }
        }

        return columnsAutoSized;
    }
```

however if I autosize columns and the content there is shorter than the header itself, the whole header is not visible, it shows three dots something like:

`this is veery long ti...` 
is there a way to fix that?